# ckeditor and mathjax - How to display Mathematical equations loaded dynamically

Tags: math, ckeditor, mathjax, ckeditor4.x

I created a simple page with CKEditor(MathJax plugin enabled) to enter Mathematical questions. Question is entered via this page and stored in database.
Sample question saved

`<p>Find the value of <span class="math-tex">\(0.5\overline{88} + 0.\overline{94}\)</span>.</p>`

Everything is fine so far.
Problem is I have another page which loads these questions via AJAX call from the database and displays these questions.
However, what I am getting is:

`Find the value of \(0.5\overline{88} + 0.\overline{94}\).`

MathJax library is loaded on this page. I figured I need to call MathJax again if the content was loaded later. But cant figure out how. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call 
`MathJax.typeset()` after loading the contents