# ckeditor mathtype output php jquery - Equations show as a straight line

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, mathtype

I'm using ckeditor 4.16 with ckeditor_wiris (math type) plugin to write math and chemistry equations. Equations in ckeditor show in the proper format, but when equations output to a paragraph or div, the equations show as a straight line.

Code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/plugins/ckwebspeech/plugin.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                    //extraPlugins: 'ckwebspeech,ckeditor_wiris',
                    extraPlugins:'ckeditor_wiris',
                    //extraPlugins:'ckwebspeech',
                    allowedContent: true
                });

            </script>
        </form>
        <button id="submit">submit</button> <br>
        The output of ckeditor math type<br>
        <p id="mathtype"></p>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
        alert(data);
        $('#mathtype').html(data);
    });
    
});
</script>
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle like this? https://jsfiddle.net/isaul32/3wjrkLdv/ or this? https://jsfiddle.net/wcvufeo9/15/  Your image is helpful, but a jsfiddle is much more helpful.  This is a client side code question that is perfect for a runnable stack snippet as well.  This might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050337/3825777

Comment: thanks for your response sir, kindly look at the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/justmasif/c3n520eg/20/